# CalendarDatePicker returns null when selecting the same date second time

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm using CalendarDatePicker binded to Property, and the Closed event binded to a method, both in my ViewModel. The LoadPage method uses SelectedDate property to load some data. Everything is working fine except for the time when i try to pick the same date that is picked already. In the converter i can see that the value picked is null and i get an exception because it cannot cast null to DateTimeOffset. Any idea why picked date end up being null? And how to fix this issue?

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var dateoffset = (DateTimeOffset)value;

        return dateoffset.Date;
    }
...

<CalendarDatePicker x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDate, 
                        Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Closed="{x:Bind ViewModel.LoadPage}">
</CalendarDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by checking in converter for null and returning DateTime.MinValue value, and then in property setter raising PropertyChanged event.
It is not really nice, i would welcome better solution.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null) return DateTime.MinValue;

        DateTimeOffset sourceTime = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        DateTime targetTime = sourceTime.DateTime;
        return targetTime;
    }


 public DateTime CurrentDate
    {
        get { return _currentDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
               RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentDate));
                return;
            }
            Set(ref _currentDate, value);
        }
    }
```